# How to make sure API call receive data before react component initial render?

Tags: reactjs

The app is a single page app, the initial render is throwing error since its rendering undefine variable.

My best guess would be invoked API call in getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) but the doc said "If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead."

Comment: Probably need a conditional render (see docs). Need to show us some code and always be specific about error messages

Comment: You can’t really block render(). Instead just use conditional rendering to only render a given element or component. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am always using is:

- set in your component state a variable 'isLoading' with an initial value of true.
- if you call the api only once, do it in your async ComponentDidMount, and once the api call completes, set isLoading to false
- in render check the variable. If true, display a spinner or a 'loading' message. If false display whatever you need in your component
- if the api is called periodically or upon an event, set the state variable to false every time you call the api and clear it when it is done